# How to reduce this $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n^n(x+n)(x+\frac{n}{2})....(x+\frac{n}{n})}{n! (x^2+n^2)(x^2+\frac{n^2}{4})...(x^2+\frac{n^2}{n^2})}\right)^\frac{x}{n} $$

max I could proceed was to take $\ln$ at both sides but not further.
I need a reduced form of this $f(x)$ (which will be found by solving the lmit?)

Please help

Comment: Duplicates: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223400/how-to-evaluate-this-limit) , [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150431/how-to-solve-this-challenging-limit?noredirect=1) , [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243109/find-fx-using-concept-of-definite-integral-as-a-limit-of-sum?noredirect=1) , [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879355/limit-of-sum-question-using-logarithm?noredirect=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent this limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312997/how-to-represent-this-limit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the Riemann integral, one can get
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln f(x)&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\ln\bigg[\left(\frac{n^n(x+n)(x+\frac{n}{2})....(x+\frac{n}{n})}{n! (x^2+n^2)(x^2+\frac{n^2}{4})...(x^2+\frac{n^2}{n^2})}\right)^\frac{x}{n}\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{n}\bigg[n\ln n-\ln(n!)+\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(x+\frac{n}{k})-\sum_{k=1}^n (x^2+\frac{n^2}{k^2})\bigg]\\
&=&x+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n\ln(x+\frac{n}{k})-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1n(x^2+\frac{n^2}{k^2})\bigg]\\\
&=&x+x\bigg[\int_0^1\ln(x+\frac1t)dt-\int_0^1\ln(x+\frac1{t^2})dt\bigg].
\end{eqnarray}
It is easy to get this two integral and I omit the detail. Here 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\bigg[n\ln n-\ln(n!)\bigg]=1 $$
is used.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with Reimann integral. Can you please send an appropriate link to understand it?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend, see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral.