# Mixed question based on the concept of limits, application of derivatives.

Tags: limits, derivatives

Question:-
[image: question]
My approach:-
[image: my approach]
After this I can't able to solve this question

Correct options are $B & C$.

Is there any other approach to solve this tough question.?
Thank You in advance for your time.

Comment: I saw the same question yesterday on this site. Can't seem to find it again.

Comment: Question may be deleted from this site ? Can you solve this problem

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150431/how-to-solve-this-challenging-limit/3150610#3150610

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-**

Put $xy= k$

After you finally get a expersion like this

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$=$ln(\frac{1+x}{1+x^2})$